# How to return correct indexing when extracting impotant features in Decision Trees

Tags: indexing, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I want to obtain the important features on my decision trees (BaggingClasifier(estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier). If I use all features of the data set (n= 8900) for the calculation, that ist max_features=1.0 (float), I can have them right indexed. However if I change max_features to any value (Ex:181), the indexes are given based on the new numbering of the set used in max_features. So, I can not know which are the actual features/important features on my original dataset.

Hier is my code:

```
dt= BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=20, min_impurity_split=0.2,
            min_samples_leaf=6, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=7,
            splitter='best'),
         bootstrap=False, bootstrap_features=True, max_features=181,
         max_samples=1.0, n_estimators=3, n_jobs=2, oob_score=False,
         random_state=7, verbose=0, warm_start=False) #min_samples_leaf=10


# Fit the model

fit_dt= dt.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print(dir(fit_dt))
trees = dt.estimators_
print(trees)

#--------------------
# Print the important features (way 1)

feature_importances = np.mean([
    tree.feature_importances_ for tree in dt.estimators_], axis=0)
print(feature_importances)


indices = np.argsort(feature_importances)[::-1]

print("Feature ranking:")

for f in range(X_train.shape[1]):
    print("%d. feature %d (%f)" % (f + 1, indices[f], feature_importances[indices[f]]))

# Plotting the trees 
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz

for i in range(0,len(dt.estimators_)): # since in dt.estimators we have a list with all trees

    t = dt.estimators_[i]
    export_graphviz(t, out_file='tree.dot') # necessary to plot the graph

    dot_data = StringIO() # need to understand but it probably relates to read of strings
    export_graphviz(t, out_file=dot_data, filled=True, class_names= target_names, rounded=True, special_characters=True)
    graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())

    img = Image(graph.create_png())
    print(dir(img)) # check what are the possibilities in graph.create_png

    with open("my_tree_" + str(i) + ".png", "wb") as png:
        png.write(img.data)
```

Returns the feature number, but not that of the original data and an error:

```
Error Message: IndexError: index 181 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 181
```

Results in case of using all features works fine

```
 Feature ranking: (my code)
1. feature 976 (0.077076)
2. feature 2119 (0.071093)
3. feature 7481 (0.065344)
4. feature 9092 (0.042598)
5. feature 7986 (0.040946)
6. feature 9642 (0.039385)
7. feature 3032 (0.039291)
8. feature 4299 (0.038662)
9. feature 8334 (0.037809)
10. feature 363 (0.037768)

    Feature raking: (@akaran code, returns different results)
    8157    0.213513
    5406    0.081889
    1461    0.078714
    7085    0.059718
    3213    0.048554
    1901    0.039385
    1486    0.038662
    1470    0.037289
    8328    0.036474
    8349    0.027375
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the output of `print dt.estimators_features_`? (in the case where you use `max_features=181`)

Comment: [array([1593, 8114,  752, 3098, 2938, 3598, 5139, 4529, ...]), array([5947, 8040, 5958, 5451,  383, 8115, 8066, 4560, 2674, 5471, 5380, ...]), array([5489, 6586, 3132, 6926,  313, 3231,  724, 6106,  274,  581,... ]) . Up to this point it gives me 181 features with the index(number) exactly as in the original data.

Comment: @mkaran if I just try to sort them, for insatnce, by np.argsort(dt.estimators_features_)[::-1], I get the same above arrays but with the index(number) from 0-181 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm this is a bit tricky since when using `max_features`, each tree will select the same number of features, e.g. 181, but they may be different.

Trying to solve this with a simpler example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

# num of features in this dataset is 4, using 2 for the example's purposes
clf = BaggingClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier(), max_features=2)
clf.fit(X, y)

print clf.estimators_features_

# get the feature importances for each tree
feat_imp = [
    tree.feature_importances_ for tree in clf.estimators_
]

# create an empty dataframe with the unique set of features 
# selected by the trees as columns
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=np.unique(clf.estimators_features_))

# iterate over the feature importances of each tree
for i in range(len(feat_imp)):
    # fill in the importances for each feature if it exists, else fill with 0
    for c in df.columns:
        df.loc[i, c] = feat_imp[i][np.where(clf.estimators_features_[i]==c)[0]][0] \
                        if c in clf.estimators_features_[i] \
                        else 0

# just to check the output
print df.head()

# get the mean for each feature sorted from the most important to the least important
print df.mean().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

The output of this will be something like this:

```
(150, 4)  # 150 rows, 4 features

# 10 estimators by default - 10 estimators_features_ different for each estimator
[array([3, 1]), array([0, 2]), array([2, 3]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 3]), array([2, 1]), array([0, 3]), array([2, 1]), array([2, 1]), array([0, 1])]

# the top rows of the dataframe that has the features used as columns 
# and the importances as values wherever applicable, else 0
          0          1         2          3
0         0  0.0323746         0   0.967625
1  0.124173          0  0.875827          0
2         0          0  0.985627  0.0143726
3  0.603425   0.396575         0          0
4  0.101683          0         0   0.898317

# the final feature importances
# feature   importance
2    0.467784
3    0.281387
0    0.155752
1    0.095078
```

I am not sure this is the most efficient way, since you have many features. Will rethink about it and edit if I come up with something better.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: thanks @mkaran, This works also for me using 10 trees. The only thing is that I am still waiting for the results from this code, even in parallell with 10 cores, when using 100 trees(which gave me better models before).

Comment: @MauroNogueira I'm glad it helped! I'll try to find a more efficient way!

Comment: Do you think I can use that trasformation you proposed also to plot the trees? In my code to obtain the trees I use the `dt.estimators_` but doing so I obtain again the new feature enumeration, not the originals. I have updated my code and included the part for plotting the trees. I would be glad if u can give me further advice.

Comment: @MauroNogueira How are you using the `dt.estimators_` to plot results? It could work but there might be an easier way to plot the trees. What do you need as an outcome?

Comment: Since I was not able to plot the trees when selecting features, I decided to run the model with all features (`max_features=1.0`). So I could get the trees plotted using my code as I added above. However when I checked the important features on the trees, they did not match with those comming from your code. Regarding `t.estimators_`, it gives me a list of the trees ready to be plotted. See one plot example above.